# How to execute Node .JS APIs test cases using Jenkinsfile

Tags: node.js, git, api, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am new to Jenkins. I have a small Node .JS server and the test cases are written using Mocha(Integration test cases, not unit test cases). I am trying to create a CI Pipeline for this using Jenkins. My Jenkinsfile looks as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Installing Dependencies...'
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Run') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting application...'
                sh 'npm start'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing...'
                sh 'npm test'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

In the run stage, the server is started using the command node server.js, Once the server is up I want the test cases to be executed against this server. But I notice that, Jenkins never executes the Test stage since the server remains started(this is what i want), and does not exit from it.
How can I have the server started and also have the test stage run against this server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved this by creating separated build jobs and then linking them together. In the run stage, I change the directory to the build folder using "cd" command and start the server. In the test stage, I do the same, but, execute the test cases on the server started in run stage.

Thank you everyone for your inputs.

Comment: More helpful would be to post your Jenkinsfile so others can also see how you exactly fixed it

Comment: I did not create a jenkinsfile. The build job itself has the configuration. I created multiple build jobs in Jenkins for setup, build, run, etc. And combined them through a Jenkins Pipeline. For more information about Build Jobs and Pipelines refer this link: https://jenkins.io/pipeline/getting-started-pipelines/

Answer (score 1):

You should run the tests before running the server. The test should not depend on the running server. Tests should require whatever is required and test, then you should run the server.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/tree/master/jenkinsfile-examples/nodejs-build-test-deploy-docker-notify

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Here I am trying to execute Integration Test cases for the server APIs. So it needs the server to be started and then run the test cases against the server. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can require the app in the test file and make requests to it. chai.request(app)
  .get('/')

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response. I have resolved it with a different approach.